# Выбрать дефолтный язык при переводе сайта через Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

Как выбрать дефолтный язык при переводе сайта через Google, т.е. Сайт на русском, плагин переводит, все нормально, но как сделать что бы при заходе он автоматом переводил на англ язык?

Comment: Какой плагин?

Comment: http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=ru Этот. называется разве не Google Translate ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Translator **автоматически выбирает язык пользователя** на основе его IP, заголовков отправленных браузером и используемой *языковой версии* Google

Comment: А если нужно чтобы страница в любом случае переводилась вне зависимости от языка пользователя?